# Double brackets

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm learning how to work with lists, and this is some command I stumbled upon:

`data = Table[{yrs[[i]], pop[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[yrs]}]`

In my Course notes it looks like this though:

[image]

Is there a way for me to get those double brackets directly on my screen? Even when I copy it, I simply get `[[ ]]`.

Comment: Hit `Esc`, type [[, hit `Esc` again. Similary for ]].

Comment: Remember you cal always start with pressing F1 when the problematic part is selected. Here it solves the problem.

Comment: Ah, I keep forgetting that! But thanks!

Comment: Nice formatting: select a cell and `ctrl` + `shift` + `n`.

Comment: @corey979 That doesn't work for me. Could the reason be that I have a Mac? When I try it, it disappears, and I can't even get it back by using `cmd` + `z`

Comment: It isn't specified [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html) that it's OS dependent. But I don't know, I'm on Linux. Someone with a mac might answer that.

Comment: @corey979 I tried out some shortcuts I'm already familiar with, and these don't work for a Mac (e.g., `ctrl`+`c` is `cmd`+`c` on Mac)

Comment: Have you tried what Kiro mentioned, the first comment?

Answer (score 1):

There is one very usefull way designed by R. Mertig. Have a look at

https://github.com/rolfmertig/Shortcuts

after installation you will have only to type F4